# How do I write "each $a$ belongs to a certain $b$

Tags: notation

I have two types of elements: $a$ and $b$. Each $a_i \in A$ belongs to only one specific $b_j \in B$. e.g.

$a_1, a_2, a_3 \in b_1, \\
a_4, a_5 \in b_2$

I could use some help with writing this in a nice mathematical expression. So far I came up with

$a_i \in b_j \forall i,j$

But I think that this says "Each element $a$ is in every element $b$." How do I write it down such that each element $a$ belongs only to one element $b$ ?

(P.S. Set theory is really not my cup of tea, so I would gladly hear of any mistakes I'm making.)

Comment: $\forall_i \exists_j a_i\in b_j$ is "each $a_i$ belongs to some $b_j$"

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Would this imply that an $a_i$ could belong to multiple $b_j$? That is not the case for me. I will update the question to better reflect this.

Comment: Then use $\exists !$. It is a bit less standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that $\exists!$ stands for "there exists a unique," so you can write, for example,

\begin{equation*}
\left(\forall a_{i}\in A\right)\left(\exists!b_{j}\in B\right)\left[a_{i}\in b_{j}\right].
\end{equation*}

You could also put more explicit emphasis on the indices. For example, if $i$ and $j$ are taken from the same index set $I$, you could write

\begin{equation*}
\left(\forall i\in I\right)\left(\exists!j\in I\right)\left[a_{i}\in b_{j}\right]
\end{equation*}

Comment: This looks perfect. The "there exists a unique" operator seems very useful in this case :)

Comment: One last question, why do you use the brackets in $[a_i \in b_j]$? Could I also write $\forall a_i \in A, \exists ! b_j \in B s.t. a_i \in b_j$ ? the "s.t." notation seems to be used often in my university.

Comment: @Chris_abc absolutely! I only used the brackets and parentheses to visually separate the different quantifiers and the statement they modify--it's just a matter of choice, as long as it's clear what you mean =)